# How do interceptors communicate with the airplane crew when the radio is dead?

Tags: radio-communications, lost-communications, flight-interception, airplane

A week ago an airplane lost the radio connection to the tower due to technical difficulties in German airspace ([article](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/stuttgart-abfangjaeger-begleiten-passagierflugzeug-a-1158019.html) in german). Thats why interceptors started to escort the plane and to check if everything was fine or an act of terrorism is happening. But how can they determine if there was a hijacking in progress of everythin is fine if the radio is dead?
**Q: How are the interceptors communicating with the airplane?**